# Hardstuck error in R: variable lengths differ

Tags: r, variables, model

I am attempting to complete Exercise 7 in page 371 of *An Introduction to Statistichal Learning with Applications in R*, where I need to train a SVM classifier to predict wether a given car has a mileage above or below the mean. The data is in the data frame Auto and has no NAs, different lengths or other obviously troublesome features (it has a column of strings stored as factors, but I have taken care of that already).

I do this with the following code

```
library("ISLR")
library("e1071")
set.seed(1)
m=dim(Auto)[1]
train=sample(1:m, ceiling(m/2), replace = FALSE)
train=sort(train)
med=median(Auto$mpg)
above_median=as.numeric(Auto$mpg[train]>=med)

length(above_median)
dim(Auto[train, -c(1,9)])

tune.out<-tune(svm, above_median ~ ., data=Auto[train,-c(1,9)], kernel="linear", 
          ranges=data.frame(cost=c(0.01, 0.03, 0.1, 0.3, 1, 3)), scale = FALSE)
```

which returns

```
Error in model.frame.default(formula, data) : 
  variable lengths differ (found for 'cylinders')
```

This is clearly not so since I have checked that all relevant lengths are 196. Also, I have checked that there are no NAs in the data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you run it this way, it works.

```
tmp <- Auto
tmp$above_median <- above_median
tune.out <- tune(svm, above_median ~ ., data=tmp[train,-c(1,9)], kernel = "linear", 
                 ranges = data.frame(cost=c(0.01, 0.03, 0.1, 0.3, 1, 3)), scale = FALSE)
```

I guess it's looking for `above_median` inside the dataframe provided, it doesn't find it, therefore Y has length 0. As a consequence, the first column doesn't have the same length.

PS: I created `tmp` not to change the orginal dataframe. Considering yours is an exercise, I suppose it doesn't matter.

Comment: It works now, thank you! By the way, does the last command take an awful lot of time to complete for you too? I guess it's just that SVM are resource expensive, but in my computer it is taking a lot of time even with four possible values for _cost_.

Comment: It took a while, yes

Comment: Actually, if you normalize the data (set `scale=TRUE`) it gets solved instantly.